# git - merge difference of branches

Tags: git, merge, git-rebase

I have three branches A, B and C.
B is regularly merged into C.

```
          o---o---o A
         /
--------o---o---o---o---o---o B
         \       \       \   \
          o---o---o---o---o---o C
```

Now I want to merge the changes I did in C, but without the merges from B, on top of A.
What is the easiest way to do this in git?

Comment: To which branch would you like to merge it?

Comment: Wouldn't that lead to a situation where you have commits Q, W (branch C), E, R (branch B) -- merge -- T, Y (branch C) and just selecting Q, W, T, Y from branch C will break things due to missing code from E, R (which probably T, Y base on)?

Comment: @MarcinGil: It might. Depends on what the changes were.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the git rebase.

First, rebase your C on top of B:

```
git checkout C
git checkout -b rebasedC #Let's do a new branch for it also, just in case
git rebase B
```

it will place all C commits on to of B.
Now we want transplant branch rebasedC from B to A:

```
git rebase --onto A B rebasedC
```

So, now you have your C-commits on top of A in the rebasedC branch. Now you can fast-forward your A to it:

```
git checkout A
git merge rebasedC
git branch -d rebasedC# I don't think you would need it.
```

That's all, I hope.

Comment: how does this get rid of B merges made in C?

Comment: Rebase does it. Then you move commits on top of B, obviously the C doesn't need the merges anymore, so they are dropped.

Comment: I've tried it with my git, now I have the tree structure: http://files.rsdn.ru/20380/git.png (the A branch here is named as 'master' instead).

Comment: You are welcome, I love the git features. Also, accept the answer to close the question.

Comment: Good answer, but the `git rebase B` is redundant.  The second rebase will also remove the merge commits if you skip the first rebase.  It might be a little easier to resolve merge conflicts in two stages, though.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using git branch -D to delete a local branch?

Comment: @WillGlass `-D` is a force delete. It is required only you are deleting unmerged branch. In my example I have merged the branch earlier.

Answer (score 2):

If i understand correctly, you want to take some commits from C into A.

If that´s the case, why don´t you "cherry-pick" them? It can lead to conflicts, but i think its your best chance :)

http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html

http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#reordering-patch-series

Answer (score 1):

You can try [cherry-picking](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cherry-pick.html) C's non-merge patches.  Be prepared to handle merge conflicts. :)